# Dominated convergence theorem with supremum and finite measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am studying measure theory and we reached the dominated convergence theorem today and I have some questions.

Is the dominated convergence theorem still true if we change the assumption

$(1)\quad|f_n| \leq g\quad $ to $(2)\quad \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \int_X |f_n| d\mu \lt \infty \quad$?

What if we add to $(2)$ that $\mu(X) \lt \infty $ is true?

Any clarifications on this are welcomed- Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not even for finite. If you google a lot of the counterexamples for the failure of this theorem in non-uniformly convergent sequences in the Riemann Integral most of them satisfy that property. For proper integrals, if its riemann integrable then it is lebesgue integrable and they have to be equal, so they fail for the lebesgue integral as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, take $X = [0,1],$ $\mu$ Lebesgue measure, and $f_n = n\chi_{(0,1/n)}.$